# Finding if a Picture Contains Grain Noise

Tags: opencv, image-processing, noise

I am trying to find if a certain picture contains grain noise. I have had ideas about how to find grain noise in a movie (comparing each frame with the previous frames), but I have no clue what to do in a single frame. I am using OpenCV and Matlab. The picture frame can be any ordinary camera shot. I would be grateful if anyone could help!

Answer (score 2):

The Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG), or any other high order edge detection filter brings out grains in the image. I would first try applying the LoG on the image and look for strong solitary edge pixels i.e. pixels that show up with a high edge intensity, while all of the neighbours are non-edges. If you find many such solitary edge pixels, the original image might be grainy.

Comment: Seems good. Any ideas about the same problem in a movie sequence? my knowledge is a little old!

Comment: The same algorithm should work, or maybe looking for solitary high intensity pixels in the difference image computed between consecutive frames of the movie sequence. There are also some complex methods to achieve this, like this one as an example: http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/pub_master.jsp?id=2001028